# Flutter - Cannot find package in .pub-cache reference

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use [tflite_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter) plugin for running a custom ml function from a tflite model. It is working fine on android but for the iOS setup, it requires us to add `TensorFlowLiteC.framework` on `~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-<plugin-version>/ios/` folder but I cannot find this folder no matter what I do. It is not just because it is hidden, the  `tflite_flutter-<plugin-version>` folder is not there at all.

I tried:

1. Adding dependency directly from git.

```
tflite_flutter:
   git:
     url: git://github.com/am15h/tflite_flutter_plugin.git
     ref: v0.9.0
```

2. Running

```
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub cache add tflite_flutter
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you won't find it in above folder as it's for `pub.dartlang.org`. try searching in `~/.pub-cache/git/` folder.
You can try my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But unfortunately, this folder doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> use_frameworks!
> pod 'TensorFlowLiteSwift'
> ```

followed by running `pod install` in your ios folder.

From official doc
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ios

As a developer, you are not bound to using flutter packages only. You can directly add dependencies to your podfile or build.gradle as well.

Comment: I did try the steps in here to manually install framework but even if I do it, I still run into issues in iOS build.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find your package in `~/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/`